# Alarm is Starting Every few Milliseconds Instead of Once Per Minute

Tags: java, android

I have an alarm I have scheduled to execute once per minute however it appears it's executing every few milliseconds (I'm getting several hundred txt msgs per minute) and I'm not sure why.

Can anyone spot the issue?

ACTIVITY SOURCE:

```
public class WifiMonitor extends Activity {

    Button sendButton;

    EditText msgTextField;

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView infoView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.traffic_info);

        double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
        double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
        totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
        totalBytes /= 1000000;
        mobileBytes /= 1000000;

        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
        String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
        String info = String.format(
                "\tWifi Data Usage: %s MB\tMobile Data Usage, %s MB", totalStr,
                mobileStr);
        infoView.setText(info);

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("7865555555", null, info, null, null);

        if (info.length() > 0) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://wifiusage.atwebpages.com/receiver.php");
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", info));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(WifiMonitor.this, Alarm.class);

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(WifiMonitor.this, 0,
                myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                pendingIntent);

    }

}
```

SERVICE SOURCE:

```
public class Alarm extends Service {

    // compat to support older devices
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        onStartCommand(intent, 0, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent Aintent = new Intent("REFRESH_THIS");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Aintent, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

        // reschedule to check again tomorrow
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(Alarm.this, Alarm.class);
        PendingIntent restartServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                Alarm.this, 0, serviceIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        // cancel previous alarm
        alarms.cancel(restartServiceIntent);

        // schedule alarm for today + 1 day
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        // schedule the alarm
        alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                restartServiceIntent);

        // send SMS
        String sms = "";
        sms += ("\tWifi Data Usage: "
                + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                        .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes()))
                / 1000000 + " MB");

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("7865555555", null, sms, null, null);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

UPDATE:

I commented out the line - alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pendingIntent); So it no longer fires every few millisecond - however it is not starting once per minute as I believe it should according to the line: calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1); (I'd like to have it set at MINUTE,1 just for testing purposes then later once I confirm it is working change it to "DAY_OF_MONTH, 1"

Comment: Use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to see what your alarms are configured as.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the trigger time to `System.currentTimeMillis()`. This causes the alarm to fire right away. Try this instead:

```
long triggerTime = System.currentTimeMIllis() + (1000 * 60);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: I actually need the alarm to fire every 30 days - I only have it set to every minute for testing purposes - so I need it to be calendar based to compensate for time the phone might be powered off

Comment: I commented out the line -  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
    pendingIntent);


So it no longer fires every few millisecond - however it is not starting once per minute as I believe it should according to the line: calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);


(I'd like to have it set at MINUTE,1 just for testing purposes then later once I confirm it is working change it to "DAY_OF_MONTH, 1"

Comment: 1. The `triggerTime` is not how long you want to wait before the alarm goes off (e.g. "1 minute"), it is the **timestamp** you want it to fire ("**the current time** plus 1 minute"). 2. Alarms are lost when the device reboots, so you need to re-initialize your app's alarms after the device reboots. You can do this with a BroadcastReceiver that received the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast.